# MVC (not mvvm) for WPF?

Tags: wpf, model-view-controller, icommand

I do not like having Controller-related code (understand ICommand stuff) in my ViewModel in WPF. Is there a framework to separate it and getting back to good old MVC for WPF?

I would like to get : 
- a view in XAML
- a view model 
- a model
- command handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Caliburn](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/) supports the MVC pattern according to the documentation. I should add a disclaimer that I've only ever used Caliburn in an MVVM context so I can't vouch for its MVC capabilities personally, but I imagine it is worth investigating.

Answer (score 1):

[ViewModel with MVC/Navigation in Silverlight](http://www.nikhilk.net/Entry.aspx?id=232)